# getIntent() and subclass of Intent

Tags: android

I wrote a class MyIntent which extends Intent.
and then i use an instance of MyIntent to invoke startActivity(MyIntent).

```
MyIntent i=new MyIntent(this,NewActivity.class);
```

the  constructor is:

```
public MyIntent(Context context,Class<?> cls){
super(context,cls);
putExtra(var1,var2);
//other codes
((Activity)context).startActivity(this);
}
```

however,when i call getIntent() in the new started activity the returned value of getIntent() is an Intent not MyIntent，that is

```
getIntent() instanceof Intent // true;
getIntent() instanceof MyIntent // false;
```

when i try (MyIntent)getIntent() the system throws me ClassCastException.How so?

Comment: What is your end goal exactly?  You want a new page to load up when you click a button?  or..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that, as Intent implements `Parcelable` and `Cloneable` interface, it's recreated  when the intent object moves across processes. Hence it will be a different instance.

In the [source code of ActivityManagerProxy, startActivity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java#ActivityManagerProxy)
You will notice that intent will not be passed by reference, instead it is written into a Parcel to create a new object. So the created Intent object in previous Activity will no longer be referred.

Comment: If subclassing Intent is not possible how does LabeledIntent then work? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/LabeledIntent.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use the copy constructor to convert your "abstract" Intent into a more concrete one. Therefore you would need to override the copy constructor of the `Intent` class and simply call super.

Say this is your intent:

```
public class StronglyTypedIntent extends Intent {
    private final static String ID = "verySecret";    

    public StronglyTypedIntent(final Activity initiator, final String someInformation) {
        super(initiator, SomeTargetActivity.class);
        putExtra(ID, someInformation);
    } 

    public StronglyTypedIntent(final Intent original) {
        super(original);
    }

    public String getSomeInformation() {
        return getStringExtra(ID)
    }
}
```

You could then initiate this intent from the "initiator activity" like this:

```
...

public void someLogicInTheInitiatingActivity() {
    startActivity(new StronglyTypedIntent(this, "some information"));
}
...
```

In the "target activity" you could get the `Intent` like this:

```
...
public void someLogicInTheTargetActivity() {
    StronglyTypedIntent intent = new StronglyTypedIntent(getIntent());

    doSomethingWithTheInformation(intent.getSomeInformation());
}
...
```

Technically this seems to be a good way to abstract the details of data transfer through intents.
However, it might be a performance problem to always copy the intent.